# Calculating percentage in a column on Blazorise datagrid

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazorise

I have a Blazor app that I am working on for sales and I am trying to work out a column for percentage. This column is not stored in the database as the calculation should happen on the web form. I cannot seem to figure out where I am going wrong, I get a `selectedItem is null` error when I run my page.

my razor page:

```
<DataGrid TItem="SalesTable"
          Data="@sales"
          Sortable="true"
          Filterable="false"
          Editable="true"
          ShowPager="true"
          PageSize="10"
          UseInternalEditing="true"
          EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Inline"
          RowUpdated="@OnRowUpdated"
          RowInserted="@OnRowInserted"
          RowRemoved="@OnRowRemoved"
          NewItemDefaultSetter="@OnNewItemDefaultSetter"
          @bind-SelectedRow="@selectedItem"
          Striped="true"
          Bordered="true"
          Hoverable="true"
          Responsive="true"
          >
      @{
            decimal percentagecalc = selectedItem.salesvalue/sumOfSales*100;
        }
        <DataGridNumericColumn  Field=@nameof(@percentagecalc) Caption="Percentage" Editable="false"></DataGridNumericColumn>
</DataGrid>
@code
{

    private List<SalesTable> sales;
    private SalesTable selectedItem;
    string selectedDropValue { get; set; }
    private decimal sumOfSales;
  

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        budgets = await SalesService.GetSalesTablesAsync();
        sumOfSales=Sales.Sum(f => f.salesvalue);
        

    }
}
```

does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Where and when do you initialize your `selectedItem`?

Comment: @BrandonStudio, I don't think selectedItem has anything to do with it... I am looking at my code now and I seemed to have made it for a bind selectedRow.

Do you perhaps know how to get a percentage working in a datagrid without the column being in a database?

Comment: You should at least show corresponding code so that we could locate the problem. I mean your `bind selectedRow`, where and how do you bind it?

Comment: @BrandonStudio I have update the question, apologies

Comment: What does your `DataGrid` tag helper belong to? It seems it is not a build-in tag helper. And your closing tag `</Datagrid>` doesn't match your opening tag `<DataGrid>`.

Comment: @BrandonStudio I am using blazorise, i have updated the code

Comment: I see. What is your final purpose? It seems you add a column to show the percentage, if you have 5 rows, you'll see 5 same percentage. Do you really want that? Or do you just want to show it once?

Comment: @BrandonStudio okay, so I have another column called sales. I wish to show the sales percentage in that percentage column. so it will be the sales value divided by the sum of sales and multiplied by 100... any idea how I could do that?

Comment: So you don't need a `selectedItem` which represents the row that user is selecting, rather, you need the **current** row, right? This may be the limitation of your "blazorise", so it may be better to ask in that community for help, or just start an issue on that repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DisplayTemplate` to create a calculated column.

```
<DataGrid TItem="SalesTable"
          Data="@sales"
          ...
          ...
          ...>
      
    <DataGridNumericColumn  Field=@nameof(SalesTable.salesvalue) Caption="Percentage" Editable="false">
        <DisplayTemplate>
            @{
                decimal percentagecalc = context.salesvalue / sumOfSales * 100;
            }            
            @percentagecalc
        </DisplayTemplate>
    </DataGridNumericColumn>

</DataGrid>
@code
{

    private List<SalesTable> sales;
    private SalesTable selectedItem;
    string selectedDropValue { get; set; }
    private decimal sumOfSales;
  

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        budgets = await SalesService.GetSalesTablesAsync();
        sumOfSales=Sales.Sum(f => f.salesvalue);
        

    }
}
```

Documentation for Blazorise DataGrid templates: https://preview.blazorise.com/docs/extensions/datagrid/templates

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that there is an `EditTemplate` tag, which might help.

```
<DataGridColumn Field="@nameof(SalesTable.salesvalue)" Caption="Percentage" Editable="false">
    <EditTemplate>
        <NumericEdit TValue="decimal" Value="@((decimal)context.CellValue)" ValueChanged="@( v => context.CellValue = v * 100 / sumOfSales)" />
    </EditTemplate>
</DataGridColumn>
```

And you may develop the usages of `context`.

Comment: An Edit tag would only come into play when an edit is done though wouldn't it

Comment: Then you can use `DisplayTemplate` instead of `EditTemplate`

Comment: @gab4bdo I'm not familiar with blazorise, you can try as Dimitris Maragkos suggests